# Best approach to design/display dashboard (kpi) using sharepoint kpi list

Tags: kpi

I have a sharepoint list with 70 kpi data points (i.e. month, goal/target, actual). What is the best way to display this data in sharepoint.

1. i tried excel powerpivot based on the sharepoint list but i couldn't get it work
2. i tried performance point but i dont have multi-dimension or cube setup for this. The data are stored in the SharePoint list

Please suggest.

Comment: can anyone shed some lights on this ?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?  There are several solutions to this, but it depends on what you are using.

Comment: SharePoint 2013. I would love to hear those options

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this third party option, there are more out there on the Googles.

http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?q=5910

Comment: company have no money right now.

Comment: You might look at chart.js then.  
http://www.sharepointsurgeon.com/create-dashboards-in-sharepoint-using-chartjs/

Comment: I dont need chart. I can use excel for chart. I need to create dashboard with kpi lights